# Making a table with elements like {10i+j, i, j}

Tags: list-manipulation, code-request

`Table[10i+j,{i,4},{j,3}]` will generate a table that looks like this:
`{{11,12,13},{21,22,23},{31,32,33},{41,42,43}}`

I would like to have a table with elements like `{10i+j, i, j}`, I mean `{{11, 1, 1}, {12, 1, 2}, ..., {43, 4, 3}}`

How do I make such a table?

Comment: Flatten[Table[{10i + j, i, j}, {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 3}], 1]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
 2)[`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking 
the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system 
is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to 
accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, 
[`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Comment: @ssch Please post that as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is one way to produce the expected result with `Table` pointed out by ssch in the comments,
here are another ones, with `Array` :

```
Array[{10 #1 + #2, #1, #2} &, {4, 3}] // Flatten[#, 1] &
```

or with a powerful function like `Outer` :

```
Outer[{10 #1 + #2, #1, #2} &, Range[4], Range[3]] // Flatten[#, 1] &
```

> ```
> {{11, 1, 1}, {12, 1, 2}, {13, 1, 3},
>  {21, 2, 1}, {22, 2, 2}, {23, 2, 3},
>  {31, 3, 1}, {32, 3, 2}, {33, 3, 3},
>  {41, 4, 1}, {42, 4, 2}, {43, 4, 3} }
> ```

Comment: Shorter: `Join @@ Array[{10 # + #2, #, #2} &, {4, 3}]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Nicer but a bit slower.

Answer (score 8):

If you create a table like:

```
Table[{10i + j, i, j}, {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 3}]
```

that nearly gives you what you want, but you'll notice they are grouped together, but that can be sorted by simply flattening that result appropriately

```
Flatten[Table[{10i + j, i, j}, {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 3}], 1]
```

Answer (score 8):

An alternative

```
{FromDigits@{##} , ##} & @@@ Tuples@Range@{4, 3}
```

Comment: +1 for being clever -- btw `{10 # + #2, ##} & @@@ Tuples@Range@{4, 3}` is shorter.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks. I prefer the longer but higher level and more extensible version

Answer (score 5):

Though not nearly as general as the method using `Table` here is a faster method for this specific case:

```
Join[#.{{10}, {1}}, #, 2] & @ Tuples @ Range @ {4, 3}
```

> ```
> {{11, 1, 1}, {12, 1, 2}, {13, 1, 3}, {21, 2, 1}, {22, 2, 2}, {23, 2, 3},
>  {31, 3, 1}, {32, 3, 2}, {33, 3, 3}, {41, 4, 1}, {42, 4, 2}, {43, 4, 3}}
> ```

Comparative timings:

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]

timeAvg[func_] := 
  Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

{x, y} = {100, 50};

{FromDigits@{##}, ##} & @@@ Tuples @ Range @ {x, y}   // timeAvg

Table[{10 i + j, i, j}, {i, x}, {j, y}] ~Flatten~ 1   // timeAvg

Array[{10 # + #2, #, #2} &, {x, y}] ~Flatten~ 1       // timeAvg

Join[#.{{10}, {1}}, #, 2] & @ Tuples @ Range @ {x, y} // timeAvg
```

> 0.004248
>
> 0.002496
>
> 0.00026976
>
> 0.00017984

`FromDigits` is clever but slow, `Array` [auto-complies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5768033/618728) and is an order of magnitude faster than `Table`, and `Dot` is faster still.

Comment: Nice analysis, `++` . Why do you use `timeAvg` instead of e.g. `AbsoluteTiming` ?

Comment: @Artes thanks.  I use it for consistency as the time taken is too short to be accurate.  I would have to create a huge array to get an accurate timing in one pass and I don't have enough RAM for that.

Comment: @Artes on second thought I could have used a larger array dimension but I would still favor `timeAvg` out of habit.

Comment: `Dot` is great and often underused, +1. I expected `FromDigits` to be slow and it clearly lived up to my expectations.

Answer (score 1):

```
Join @@ Table[{10 i + j, i, j}, {i, 4}, {j, 3}]
Sequence @@@ Table[{10 i + j, i, j}, {i, 4}, {j, 3}]
Tuples[Range@{4, 3}] /. {x_, y_} -> {10 x + y, x, y}
Level[#, {2}] &@Table[{10 i + j, i, j}, {i, 4}, {j, 3}]
```